# Turning off GNU Octave terminal output

Tags: command-line-interface, octave

I am used to cli, and find Octave very useful for solving linear algebraic equations and image processing stuff.

However there is one thing that annoys me - it outputs **every** variable's value which is excessive when you have a large matrix.

Is there any way I can turn it off and output variable's value manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it appears that all you need to do is [to put a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the line](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-Examples.html) you want to run silently.

So instead of:

```
c = a + b
```

Try:

```
c = a + b;
```

You may also [call Octave with either the `-q`, `--quiet`, or `--silent` command-line argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Options.html) to avoid printing the greeting and version message.